# Database Table is not being saved

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I created a database in visual studio 2019 and now I am trying to create a table. I insert all the attributes and press the save button, I choose the directory and again press save, but the new table doesn't show up in the server explorer. I checked the files and somehow the table is saved there but I can't access it. I tried to save it again but the same thing happens.
The SQL code is correct as I Checked it multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the Update button once you finish editing the table.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I was going to click it the moment I solved it, but StackOverflow makes you wait 2 days to mark your own solution.

Answer (score 2):

In the SQL Server Object Explorer under 'Databases' select the database you're working with, right click, and select Refresh.  Your table should now appear in the list of Tables.

Comment: I had forgotten to press the update button after I finished the table.